# Inverse function theorem, Tao, Analysis II

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, differential-geometry, inverse-function-theorem

In Analysis II by Tao, he wrote:

Theorem 6.7.2 (Inverse function theorem).

Let $E$ be an open subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$, and let $f : E \to \mathbf{R}^n$ be a function which is continuously differentiable on $E$. Suppose $x_0 \in E$ is such that linear transformation $f'(x_0) : \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^n$ is invertible. Then there exists an open set $U$ in $E$ containing $x_0$, and an open set $V$ in $\mathbf{R}^n$ containing $f(x_0)$, such that $f$ is a bijection from $U$ to $V$. In particular, there is an inverse map $f^{-1} : V \to U$. Furthermore, this inverse map is differentiable at $f(x_0)$, and
$$
(f^{-1})'(f(x_0)) = (f'(x_0))^{-1}.
$$

From errta of this book on his blog, he wrote:

Exercise 6.7.4. Let the notation and hypotheses be as in Theorem 6.7.2. Show that, after shrinking the open sets U, V if necessary (while still having $x_0 \in U$, $f(x_0) \in V$ of course), the derivative map $f'(x)$ is invertible for all $x \in U$, and that the inverse map $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at every point of $V$ with $(f^{-1})'(f(x)) = (f'(x))^{-1}$ for all $x \in U$. Finally, show that $f^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable on $V$.

I try to solve this exercise by looking for the relation between $f'(x)$ and $f'(x_0)$ for $x$ near $x_0$, but so far I got nothing.
I also try to google proofs, turn out the exercise I'm tring to proof is **given as a part of the hypothesis**.

To conclude, I am looking for the answers of the following questions:

1. How to proof the exercise for functions $f : \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^n$? (Tao already explained the case $f : \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$.) More specifically, proof the exercise **without** using some prior knowledge in **linear algebra** just like the way Tao proof the inverse function theorem (like determinants, etc. I did not learn linear algebra before).
2. How to interpret the result of the exercises (with graph) ?
3. Which parts of the given **hypotheses** are **necessary**?

Comment: You must use the fact that $f$ is continuously differentiable. This implies that the map $df$ is continuous as a function of $x$ with values in the linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into itself. This allows you to conclude that it is invertible in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ (e.g by looking at the determinant of $df(x)$, which is also continuos).

Comment: I'm not familiar with determinant (or property of linear algebra), so can you write down the proof of your claim?

Comment: Without any linear algebra this will be difficult. You don't need the determinant, but you will need to somehow show that $df$ is invertible in a neighbourhood of $x_0$, using the fact that it is continuous.

Comment: I thought the same thing before, and I tried your suggestion, but I got nothing (as I mentioned in the text). Can you give more hints?

Comment: Not now, sorry, I don't have the time. That's why I wrote a comment in the first place.

Comment: You should pause and study linear algebra first. It’s a fundamental subject and is needed everywhere, including analysis.